# Simple way to change a pivot cache

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This doesn't work...

```
Sub changeData_Error()

Dim pc As PivotCache
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("A1:B2"))
Excel.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache pc

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Have ended up with the following which seems over complicated. Can it be simplified?

```
Sub changeData()

 ':: this is the table I'd like to change the data
Dim mainP As PivotTable
Set mainP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

 ':: create a new cache and set it to the new data range
Dim pc As PivotCache
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("A1:B3"))

 ':: create a temporary pivot table
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables.Add(pc, Range("AA1"), "temptable")

 ':: find the index of the cache used by the temp table
Dim i As Integer
i = pt.CacheIndex
 ':: use the index found to redirect the main pivot at the new cache
mainP.CacheIndex = i

 ':: get rid of temp table
pt.TableRange2.Clear

 ':: this might not be needed
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code switches between two different datasets, easily seen visibly by the presence/absence of **Col3** in the Field List for the Pivot report:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SwitchToData1()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    SwitchCacheData _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1"), _
        Range("Data1!A1:B4")
EndSub:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number * vbCrLf & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _
        "Error!"
    Resume EndSub
End Sub


Public Sub SwitchToData2()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    SwitchCacheData _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1"), _
        Range("Data2!A1:C4")
EndSub:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number * vbCrLf & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _
        "Error!"
    Resume EndSub
End Sub

Private Sub SwitchCacheData(pvt As PivotTable, rng As Range)
    pvt.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rng)
    pvt.RefreshTable
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Hi Pieter - thanks for this nice post. Can you see why my original snippet does not execute?

Comment: @whytheq: Are you performing a **RefreshTable** anywhere on your PivotTable?